# \n line break in asp.net core mvc not working for last string word

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

`var description="some text"+"\n some text 2" +"\n some text 3";

Out put:
some text 
some text 2 some text 3.

why some text 3 is also showing with some text 2 instead of breaking line.`

Comment: @ThilokGunawardena No ,i am showing it in browser view asp.net core mvc.
why line is not breaking for 3rd string ,it is showing 3rd string with string 2 why ?

Comment: I'm confused here. Is it your assumption that \n will actually produce a line break in output html?

Comment: html ignores line breaks

Comment: @Darkonekt yes it making problem in html view.

Comment: showing output as
<p > some text<br>                                                                                                           some text 2 some text 3 </p>

Answer (score 3):

I find solution,to show string data of asp.net mvc with break line,use style attribute     "white-space: pre-wrap" on Html element.